# Concatenate numbers with leading 0

Tags: excel

I have two columns and I want to do a formula to put them on the same cell and keep the leading 0 in the second column.

Ex.:

First colum:
5, 4, 3, 2

Second column:

01, 002, 00003 , 1234

Result wanted in my third column:
501, 4002, 300003, 21234

when I try to put my second column in text, 0's disappear so I can't use formula with & or CONCATENATE. In my original file the numbers are custom. Another problem is that sometimes I have more or less 0's so I cannot add them with a text("000") kind of formula.

I'm new to Excel and to Stackoverflow so let me know if you want me to fix my post. I will be more than happy to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: If there is no pattern in the number of leading zeros then each cell is formatted differently and using a formula will not work.  You will need vba to loop and read the format from each cell then apply that  when concatenating.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to make sure I was not missing something...

Comment: I guess, I am missing an important point. How do the values in column 2 look like? I mean, if they show the leading zeros (as in your example), they must be formated as text already and in that case `A2&B2` would provide `501`.

Comment: They are "custom" number. I extracted a PDF in Excel to use the data, so I think it's all different form of values. I tried to switch them in text, but the leading 0 disappeared. If I let them as custom number they look exactly how I wrote them in my question.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot or upload a sample worksheet?

Comment: I don't know how to directly post a screenshot here, so you can find it here: https://imgur.com/hQhNS2v I want to put column C, D together and E, F.